# How to create auto iteration in for loop which would assign pointer instead of value to it

Tags: c++, iteration, auto

I want to create auto iteration loop like this:

```
std::vector<sometype> vector1;
for(auto it : vector1)
{
   if(&it == &vector1.at(4))
      //do something...
   else
      continue;
}
```

but I found out that adress of "it" when it's equal to vector1.at(4) is not the same as adress of vector1.at(4). How can I do for loop which would assign to "it" not value but adress of value currently pointing to.

Comment: The answer below explains *how* to do this, but may I ask *why* you want to do this? e.g. in this particular case, you could just `// ... do something` with `vector.at(4)` directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reference (add `&` to variable declarations) to do something like that.

```
std::vector<sometype> vector1;
for(auto& it : vector1) // add &
{
   if(&it == &vector1.at(4))
      //do something...
   else
      continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code as pseudo-code for an algorithm, it basically attempts to solve

1. Check (via O(n) instead of O(1) cost) if the vector has at least 5 elements.

   - If `true`, go to 2.
   - Otherwise do nothing.
2. Do something with the 5th element.

If this is indeed the case, you don't actually need a for loop for this, you could just query the size of the vector prior to conditionally accessing (O(1) random access) the 5th element to `//do something...`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const std::vector<std::string> v{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
    if (v.size() > 4) { 
        auto s = v[4];
        // do something with the 5th element, as it exists.
        std::cout << e; // d
    }
}
```

Or, you could make use of the bounds-checking element accessor [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) clong with exception handling in case of attempted out-of-bounds access.

Answer (score 0):

In the range-based for loop

```
std::vector<sometype> vector1;
for(auto it : vector1)
{
   if(&it == &vector1.at(4))
      //do something...
   else
      continue;
}
```

`it` is not an iterator. It is an object of the type `sometype` that stores the value of the corresponding element in the vector.

Instead of creating an object you should use a reference as for example

```
std::vector<sometype> vector1;
for( auto &value : vector1)
{
   if( &value == &vector1.at(4))
      //do something...
   else
      continue;
}
```

Pay attention that the else statement with continue does not make a great sense. You could write simply

```
std::vector<sometype> vector1;
for( auto &value : vector1)
{
   if( &value == &vector1.at(4))
      //do something...
}
```

Though it is unclear why you are using the range-based for loop when only one element of the vector will satisfy the condition.